# I am getting build failed while running ant sonar. As my sonar server is up

Tags: sonarqube

I am getting build failed while doing ant sonar. Now I am working on sonarqube 6.4. I am working in Hybris. I have given my error msg with build.xml part were error I am getting

1. I have installed new version of Sonarqube but it didn't work for me.
2. I fetch my whole code again with git but again not work.

Error Message:

```
BUILD FAILED C:\DukeHybrisNew\hybris\bin\platform\build.xml:82: The following error occurred while executing this line: 
C:\DukeHybrisNew\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\sonar.xml:89: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to blame file 
src/com/duke/backoffice/service/DukeBackofficeService.java at 
org.sonarsource.scm.git.JGitBlameCommand.blame(JGitBlameCommand.java:128) at 
org.sonarsource.scm.git.JGitBlameCommand.access$000(JGitBlameCommand.java:44)
```

Comment: BUILD FAILED
C:\DukeHybrisNew\hybris\bin\platform\build.xml:82: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\DukeHybrisNew\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\sonar.xml:89: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to blame file src/com/duke/backoffice/service/DukeBackofficeService.java
        at org.sonarsource.scm.git.JGitBlameCommand.blame(JGitBlameCommand.java:128)
        at org.sonarsource.scm.git.JGitBlameCommand.access$000(JGitBlameCommand.java:44)

Comment: <target name="sonar" description="Deprecated. Executes sonar to check all projects with the sonar rules.">
        <callback extname="" target="before_sonar"/>
        <sonar extensions="${extension.names}"/>
        <callback extname="" target="sonar_pmd"/>
    </target>

Comment: Are you executing your Ant task from the root of your project? `Unable to blame file` typically indicates SonarQube can't find the Git information for your projects, or the file its complaining about isn't in the Git index.